# Using NSKeyedUnarchiver to read in a file created with writeToFile:atomically:

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocoa, nsdictionary, plist, archive

Is there a difference between these methods when reading an `NSDictionary` from a file which was written by `writeToFile:atomically:`?

```
[someDict writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

Reading by:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:filePath];
```

vs

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

Comment: The second one will work; the firs one wouldn't.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight will the first one work with NSArrays (i mean with NSArray's writeToFile method) or should i use it with only files I wrote with NSKeyedArchiver?

Comment: You should use the first method only with files that you wrote with `NSKeyedArchiver`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes: the first option won't work at all.

`NSKeyedArchiver` and `writeToFile:` don't use the same format. The `writeToFile:atomically:` description says:

> Writes a property list representation of the contents of the dictionary to a given path.

Whereas a keyed archive is

> an architecture-independent stream of bytes that preserves the identity of and the relationships between the objects and values.

It's more flexible in that it can encode any object that conforms to `NSCoding`, as opposed to just [property list objects](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/PropertyList.html).

Files created using one procedure can't be read with the other.